# What does this sequence ../.. mean in command line?

Tags: command-line

I don't know how to interpret `some_command ../..`. What does `../..` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`..` indicates the parent directory of current working directory. So, `../..` indicates the parent directory of the parent directory of the current directory.

`some_command ../..` means the `some_command` takes the directory name as argument e.g. `ls` or `cd`.

**Example:**

```
/foobar/grandparent/parent% cd ../..

/foobar%
```